# Encode JSON in PHP and submit with POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

**Problem:**

I have a variable which is encoded in JSON and I'm stuck trying to figure out how this variable can be sent to a PHP page using jQuery/AJAX.

This is what I have tried so far.

1. The file is uploaded using http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/
2. It gets processed by jQuery according to the JS code below.

**JS code:**

```
<script>    
    $(function () {
        'use strict';
        // Server-side upload handler:
        var url = 'process.php';

        $('#fileupload').fileupload({
            url: url,
            autoUpload: true,
            acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(txt)$/i,
            maxFileSize: 5000000, // 5 MB               
            done: function (e, data) {

                setTimeout(function(){
                    $("#loading").html("Loading...");}, 1000);

                var formUrl = 'exec.php',

                // You'll have to re-encode to JSON, probably:
                formPerspective = JSON.stringify(data.result.formPerspective),

                // This is the newly added value ( Maybe this needs JSON aswell? )
                formTxtfile = JSON.stringify(data.result.formTxtfile),

                // Generate the form
                $form = $('<form action="'+ formUrl +'" method="post"></form>')
                        .append('<input type="hidden" name="Perspective" value="' + formPerspective + '">')
                        .append('<input type="hidden" name="Datafile" value="' + formTxtfile + '">')
                        .append('<input type="hidden" name="form_submitted">');

                // Submit the form
                $form.submit();
            },

            progressall: function (e, data) {
                var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
                    'width',
                    progress + '%'
                );
            }
        }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
            .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
    });
</script>
```

1. As you can see, it calls the PHP handler which is according to the code below.

**PHP code:**

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $folder      = 'upload';

    if (!empty($_FILES))
    {
        // Set temporary name
        $tmp    = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'];

        // Set target path and file name
        $target = $folder . '/' . $_FILES['files']['name'];

        // Upload file to target folder
        $status = move_uploaded_file($tmp, $target);

        if ($status)
        {
            // Set session with txtfile name
            $_SESSION['txtfile']    = $_FILES['files']['name'];

            $text_file    = file('upload/' . $_SESSION['txtfile']);

            foreach ($text_file as $line_number => $line)
            {               
                if (strpos($line, "\t") === 0)
                {
                    // Remove commented column names and first \t
                    $dimensions = explode("\t", preg_replace("#\t/.+#", '', substr($line, 1)));
                }               
            }

            // Set dimensions
            $_SESSION['dimensions'] = str_replace('\n', '', $dimensions);

            $jsonReturn = array(
                'formPerspective'   => $_SESSION['dimensions'],
                'formTxtfile'       => $_SESSION['txtfile']
            );

            // Convert to JSON
            $encode = json_encode($jsonReturn);

            echo $encode;
        }
    }
?>
```

**Desired solution:**

I would like to take the information in `$encode` and send it using POST to the page "oe.lc". On OE.lc the variable is picked by using:

`$_POST["Perspective"]`

In addition, OE.lc checks if a form is submitted using:

`$_POST["form_submitted"]`

The JS should redirect to OE.lc upon submission (now it redirects to explorer.php).

Any ideas?

Comment: Ideas for what? What is the problem? No question or problem description here...

Comment: I want the array in $encode to be sent to "oe.lc" through JS. The array should be sent as a POST variable so it can be picked up by oe.lc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to simply echo the `$encode` and then exit the script by using `die();`

**Edit:** You said you would like to add extra values to the form, first you need to change the php file that determines the return to Javascript in JSON:

```
$jsonReturn = array(
    'formPerspective' => $dimensions,
    'formTxtfile' => $_SESSION['txtfile'],
);

// Convert to JSON
$encode = str_replace('\n', '', json_encode($jsonReturn));

// The above will print out the following when echoed:
// {'formPerspective':["legs","skincover","weight","intelligence","speed"], 'formTxtfile': 'Not sure what this holds as data'}

die($encode);
```

The data should then be in `data.result` in the `done` callback you configured.

You probably want to forward the browser to oe.lc, how about you generate a form and submit that?

**Edit:** We should add our newly accuired value here:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
        // ...
        done: function (e, data) {
                // Determine the url:
            var formUrl = 'http://oe.lc',

                // You'll have to re-encode to JSON, probably:
                formPerspective = JSON.stringify(data.result.formPerspective),

                // This is the newly added value ( Maybe this needs JSON aswell? )
                formTxtfile = JSON.stringify(data.result.formTxtfile),


                // Generate the form
                $form = $("<form action='"+ formUrl +"' method='post'></form>")
                        .append("<input type='hidden' name='Perspective' value='" + formPerspective + "'>")
                        .append("<input type='hidden' name='Datafile' value='" + formTxtfile + "'>")
                        .append("<input type='hidden' name='form_submitted'>")
                        .appendTo('body');

                // Submit the form
                $form.submit();
        },
        // ...
    });
```

Please let me know if that works for you!

Comment: yeah! sending the form values would be better so that they can be retrieved in oe.lc page +1

Comment: I think we are on the right way, only one detail remains. I need to include another form input. This value is generated in process.php as $_SESSION['txtfile'], how can I return both this value and the $encode back?

Comment: Yes, you can add that to the initial `$encode`, I'll update my answer to reflect this for you.

Comment: Excellent, and thanks. Let me know when the answer is updated and I will give it a try.

Comment: There you go. There are numerous ways you can improve on this probably ( maybe by automatically adding all values found in the json to the form, etc. )

Comment: Still doesn't work, both variables are being printed out as "undefined". I have updated the PHP and JS code so you can see how it looks.

Comment: Arg I see it, it's the double quotes I use in the form html, json is with double quotes, setting up the form with single quotes should work fine. I edited my answer. **Edit:** Come to think of it this should not fix the undefined values. Did you try to check the return from PHP using Dev Tools? https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/?hl=nl ?

Comment: I got it working with above code. A json_decode gives me a perfect array of the values from the text file in exec.php.

Comment: Still doesn't work and the problem is here: formPerspective = JSON.stringify(data.result.formPerspective) and here: formTxtfile = JSON.stringify(data.result.formTxtfile) - although the values are added, they are not returned to the function.

Comment: Sorry, that's obvious, my bad! JSON.stringify() is only supported by major browsers, what browser are you using? You could try implementing json2.js from https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js ( from http://www.json.org/ ), this adds the JSON object, and thus the JSON.stringify() method, to browsers that do not support it.

Comment: I actually removed JSON.stringify() and now the solution works perfectly in Chrome 31.0.1650.57, Safari 7.0 (9537.71) but not in Firefox 25.0.1. Any ideas? The form does not submit in FF.

Comment: Try adding the form to the body before submit `.appendTo('body');` FF could have an issue with that. I updated the code above.

Comment: Works like a CHARM! I would totally buy you a drink for this :-)

Comment: You're welcome, buy one for yourself, you helped yourself too! Then I'll just buy one for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code (not working in Firefox though):

```
<script>    
    $(function () {
        'use strict';

        // Server-side PHP upload handler
        var url = 'process.php';

        // File upload handler
        $('#fileupload').fileupload({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            autoUpload: true,
            acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(txt)$/i,
            maxFileSize: 5000000, // 5 MB               
            done: function (e, data) {

                // Output alert message
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $("#loading").html("Loading...");}, 1000);

                // Form destination
                var formUrl = 'test.php',

                // Variables to be sent with the form
                formPerspective = data.result.formPerspective,
                formTxtfile = data.result.formTxtfile,

                // Generate the form
                $form = $("<form action='"+ formUrl +"' method='post'></form>")
                        .append("<input type='hidden' name='Perspective' value='" + formPerspective + "'>")
                        .append("<input type='hidden' name='Datafile' value='" + formTxtfile + "'>")
                        .append("<input type='hidden' name='form_submitted' value='true'>")
                        .appendTo('body');

                // Submit the form
                $form.submit();
            },

            // Progress indicator
            progressall: function (e, data) {
                var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
                    'width',
                    progress + '%'
                );
            }
        }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
            .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
    });
</script>
```